# Infinity Pistol drop in True Vault Hunter Mode?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've been searching for this all over again and again but I can't seem to find a specific answer. When I go to the Borderlands wiki they say they upped the drop rate of the Infinity Pistol **"for all game modes"** yet, I still see in the Gearbox Community forums that they still haven't received the Infinity Pistol drop from Doc Mercy.

Will I get the Infinity Pistol from Doc Mercy on True Vault Hunter Mode?
*btw I have the relic that increases the drop rate by 5% so yeah...
*I'm playing on the PC doe, Steam.

*On a side note/question:*
In Normal Mode, is there anyway to increase the level of the Infinity Pistol that Doc Mercy Drops? I've been getting 7's and 6's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the Infinity Pistol drops in True Vault Hunter Mode (TVHM) but its droprate is bugged (Bugged in TVHM and UTVHM). The droprate is incredible low and as you can see in other borderlands forums you see that people got infinity pistols in TVHM after 1000+ kills too. With my Mechromancer I killed Doc Mercy like 1200 times without one Infinity Pistol dropping, but with my Assassin i got it after a few kills.

All you need is more luck..

Comment: I have lots of hundreds of hours on Borderlands 2, never seeing one. And then this one time we start new characters with my wife and I notice she casually uses a level 12 Infinity...